# css-grid auto-fit creating extra empty column when not needed

Tags: css, css-grid

[image: auto-fit creating extra empty columns]

this is the css of the section. The container of the images is 'main' and each image is inside an 'article' tag

```
main {
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 1em;
}

article:nth-of-type(3){
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

I am using css-grid and `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))` to create columns and wrapping them automatically but as seen in image, auto-fit is creating extra empty columns for some reason. I thought this was the behavior of `auto-fill` and in `auto-fit` empty columns are collapsed automatically.
[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/html-css-forked-wv5ur?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Can you provide enough code to constitute a [mcve] (ideally as a snippet in the question)?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/html-css-forked-wv5ur?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `article:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}` will create as many columns of at least 300px to fill/span the entire width of the grid. Nothing wrong with your code ;(

Comment: why though, empty grid cell have to be collapsed and the space redistributed among rest of cells. if not, what is the difference between 'auto-fill' and 'autof-fit'

Comment: cells do not collapse, they are just there, but they can span. you set the mimal size to 300px, you have it ;) ... but if 300px is a need, you can from that use a mediaquery to manage so many columns and gap to mind nth-child(3) positionning or use a max-width: possible partial update example `main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1em;
  justify-content:center;
  max-width:max-content;
  margin:auto;
}

article:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  max-width:800px;
}`

Comment: live example of the idea : https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-pq65p?file=/styles/base.css

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/
see the italicised section in "fill or fit ? What's the difference".
In auto-fit the empty cells are collapsed.